# How to toggle between 2g and 3g in Android

Tags: android, 3g

- Please give me some keyworkds to toggle between 2g and 3g in Android by code.
- If you have code snippets. Please give me.
- Thanks for all

  - Nguyen Dai Son

Answer (score 0):

Setting you need is from Settings.Secure.NETWORK_PREFERENCE from the android.provider package. Since secure settings is only allowed for reading, I do not see any regular way to do that. Please correct me if that was not true.

Regarding reading of this setting, beware, I have not tried, but some bug was reported related to that.